# Grails get id in each tag

Tags: grails, controller

Hey. How can i get the current temp id to pass to the controller in the glink? (####)?

```
<g:each in="${temp}">

  <li>Date: ${it.dateParticipated}, <br>Role: ${it.role}, <br>Acceptence: ${it.accepted}, <br>
  <g:link controller="conference" action="participated" params="[temp: it.conference.id]">
     Conference: </g:link>${it.conference},<br>
Status: ${it.status}<br>
<g:link controller="conferenceUser" action="edit1" params="[temp2: it]">#####
    - Update </g:link></li>

  <br>
</g:each>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add an "id" attribute.

```
<g:link controller="conferenceUser" action="edit1" id="${it.id}" params="[temp2: it]">#####
        - Update </g:link>
```